# RequireJS and Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, requirejs, prototypal-inheritance

I'm running into an issue with using RequireJS and Prototypal inheritance. Here's my module:

```
define(function () {
  function Module(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  Module.prototype.getData = function () {
    return this.data;
  };

  Module.prototype.doSomething = function () {
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log(this.getData());
  };

  return Module;

  Module.prototype.callFunction = function (fn) {
    if (this[fn]) {
      console.log('call');
      Module.prototype[fn]();
    }
  };
});
```

Then I instantiate the module, like so:

```
var module = new Module({ name: 'Marty' });
module.getData(); // returns { name: 'Marty' }
module.data; // returns { name: 'Marty' }
module.callFunction('doSomething') // returns undefined on the first (and second) console log
```

The `console.log`s in the `module.doSomething()` always return `undefined`. Am I misunderstanding how prototypal inheritance works with RequireJS?

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Are you wrapping your instantiation code in require()? When I try your approach and wrap the last block in require(), I get a 'Module is not defined' error.

Comment: Yes, it's being instantiated in a require() or from within another AMD module like so: define(['module-file-from-my-example-above'], function () { /* .. instantiate here */ }); Also, make sure the return statement in your AMD module is the last thing before the closing '});'. Don't know how I managed to mis-type that one.  In case you need help with including AMD modules in your HTML, http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html is a good place to start.

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much - this helps me a great deal. I'll award you the bounty points as soon as Stack allows. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it. And thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I had written the callFunction method incorrectly.  The correct way is:

```
Module.prototype.callFunction = function (fn) {
  if (this[fn] && typeof this[fn] === "function") {
    this[fn]();
  }
};
```

The problem was using `Module.prototype` instead of `this`. Whoops.